# How to connect to azure devops from powershell in yaml pipelines?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are trying to execute this `az devops service-endpoint list` in a powershell script added in a pipeline in yaml from Azure DevOps

```
$SubscriptionId = az devops service-endpoint list --organization "https://dev.azure.com/xxxxx" --project $ProjectName --query "[?data.subscriptionName==$SubscriptionName].data.subscriptionId" -o tsv
```

For executing the command above, The logs tell that we need to login using `az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/` , how do we do this in the pipeline?

Also we use the system access token variable for logging in like this:

```
$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
```

Comment: Try [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops#example) task. You would be able to pass a service connection as input to this task. You also don't need to do `az login` separately if you use this task.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Tejas Nagchandi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3954965/tejas-nagchandi). Posting your suggestion as an answer so that it will be helpful for other community members as well who is facing similar kind of issues.

Below is the sample code of Azure CLI task and try to use that by which you can pass a service connection as input and with the help of this task no need to use az-login as well.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Azure CLI
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: <Name of the Azure Resource Manager service connection>
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az --version
      az account show
```

for further details check the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops#example) task documentation.